# How are SOAP headers processed in Camel-CXF?

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

I'm trying to wrap my head around Apache Camel using Jboss Fuse 6.2.1 and I don't understand how SOAP headers are being processed.

I have a WSDL from which I have generated classes for my input and output messages. The input consists of a header and a body while the output only consists of a body.

**WSDL**

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://cxftestserver.blueprint.me.com">
        <xs:element name="input">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Id" />
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="output">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Code" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://cxftestserver.blueprint.me.com/authentication">
        <xs:element name="authHeader">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="username" />
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="password" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="inputTest">
    <wsdl:part name="header" element="tns1:authHeader" />
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="tns:input" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="outputTest">
    <wsdl:part name="out" element="tns:output" />
</wsdl:message>
```

**Blueprint**

```
<bean id="myProcessor" class="com.me.blueprint.cxftestserver.MyProcessor" />

<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="test-ws" address="/Test" serviceClass="com.me.blueprint.cxftestserver.TestEndpoint" />

<camel:camelContext>
    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="cxf:bean:test-ws" />
        <camel:process ref="myProcessor" />
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

What I don't understand now is why the Message-body inside of the Exchange contains both the authHeader and the input? Every example I've read in the docs suggest that I should be able to extract the header by doing:

```
exchange.getIn().getHeaders(//insert your favorite parameter here);
```

but whenever I've tried that it would always return null. I wasted several hours looking in all the wrong places when I finally found that the Message-body contained the MessageContentsList-object holding both my SOAP-header and my SOAP-body.

```
Message inMessage = e.getIn();
AuthHeader header = inMessage.getBody(AuthHeader.class);
Input body = inMessage.getBody(Input.class);
```

Can someone please explain to me why and when this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've found the answer to my initial question:

According to the documentation I've now come to understand that, when using POJO as data format, the consumer-endpoint looks at what parameters the requested method has in my **SEI** (Service Endpoint Interface (to which the serviceClass-attribute points.))

These parameters are then invoked into the Message-body (MessageContentsList-object) which would explain why both the header and the body are present.

Answer (score 1):

All depends on what dataFormat you prefer to use, for eg: if you use dataFormat=MESSAGE. Then you will be able to see the whole incoming message in your exchange, basically the whole message including headers will come in as a string. You can handle it straight away using xpath.

> Refer this example for dataFormats -
>   https://github.com/gnanagurus/camel-guru-projects/blob/master/camel-cxf-geocoder-example/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/beans-config.xml

But whatever they have suggested is also right, You can extract it using getHeaders(). Can you try configuring the CXF endpoint as mentioned in this example & make the dataFormat to be 'PAYLOAD'. (Basically in PAYLOAD you will get the soap body as a exchange body, rest in headers) I am sure, you will be able to read your headers using getHeaders().

Also, is there a reason why you have defined your CXF endpoint using your service class / why you have to generate your classes. If you have a reason ignore it, I tend to avoid classes in camel projects, rather I try the best to use the framework capabilities in XML itself. If you want to expose a SOAP based web service endpoint using camel, You don't have to generate any classes yourself - this example can lead/help you:

> https://github.com/gnanagurus/camel-guru-projects/tree/master/camel-cxf-geocoder-example
>
> Description about the above example:
>   http://bushorn.com/camel-web-services-expose-them/

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should add that it isn't a problem for me the way my header is being processed as I now know where to find it. I just don't understand why the header is found within the message-body rather than the headers. I've only played around with Camel for about a week so I haven't had time to explore all the data formats yet but surely there must be scenarios where POJO is preferable over MESSAGE and PAYLOAD?

Comment: I think, it depends on what you prefer the payload type should be. I always prefer to use xslt's with camel and at the moment, most of my services are internal, so I found dataformat MESSAGE + XSLT is a good choice, its more visible.